# extra characters inserted in strings (I inserted the null character '\0')

Tags: c++, string, fstream, randomaccessfile

I've been having troubles with the read() member function of the fstream object of the STL. I have a class ClientData with four members variables (int accountNumber, string firstName, string lastName, double balance).

**When I read the information, I get some extra characters at the end of each string that were not typed. If I type "AVeryLongWord" and after that a "ShortOne" the result is "ShortOnegWord" or something of the sort.**

I have a ClientData object called clientData and to store/retrieve the information, I use the following statements:

To write:

```
nombrArchivo.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&clientData), sizeof(clientData));
```

And to read the data I use:

```
archivo.seekg(0);
archivo.read(reinterpret_cast< char*>(&cliente), sizeof(ClientData));
```

To set the strings I use:

```
int length = fName.size();
length = length<15?length:14;
fName.copy(firstName, length);
fName[length]='\0';
```

The whole thing is [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzO7yVs6k0ZCMGtEdnl2Q0FLT28&usp=sharing). It's a CodeBlocks(13.12) project with Mingw (GCC 4.6).

Comment: What are `clientData` and `cliente`?

Comment: I do not really see what you are doing here, but it looks like you take the pointer to the beginning of the string, write 'AVeryLongWord0' inside, then you overwrite the same memory by putting 'ShortOne' at the beginning of it. This naturally results in the mangled word you get. Could you write a minimal program illustrating your problem rather than dumping your whole thing? You'll probably identify the problem in the process.

Comment: @AtlasC1 clientData and cliente are objects of the ClientData class.

Comment: @Josef Legény (YOU WERE RIGHT) I found the problem. It was in the code I posted. I started reviewing from the start until the end and I saw that I was inserting the null character in the wrong string. I inserted the '\0' in the fName string instead of firstName were the copy function never coipied the null char.